# Debugging a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file that is supposed to iterate through all .csv files in a folder and do the following with each one:  MOVE/Rename it to solar.csv in a different folder while overwriting any file with the same name, start some service that utilizes solar.csv, wait 7.5 minutes, stop the service.  This should be done for each .csv file in the folder.  I would like it to report each step as it does it as well.  Here is my code so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "D:\PI Data Import\Data"

For /R %%G IN (*.csv) DO (

MOVE /Y %%G.csv "D:\PI Data Import\solar.csv"
ECHO "%%G.csv Moved"
NET START RDBMSPI4
ECHO "Service Started"
ECHO "Waiting"
TIMEOUT /T 450 /NOBREAK
NET STOP RDBMSPI4
Echo "%%G.csv Complete"

)
```

It reports that my command syntax is not correct, but doesn't say which part exactly.  I assume the FOR /R line is a bit wrong, maybe the MOVE command, and possibly how I handle the %%G in the command section.

All I really need is a syntax check, and I am afraid to test this too terribly much before it is golden since the server it will operate on is kind of important.  All help appreciated, I'm not at all experienced with working on Batch files.

Comment: For general debugging, I would recommend removing/commenting out the `@ECHO OFF` command so you can see the last command being processed when the error was produced.

Comment: If any of your CSV files have spaces in it, you will get an error on your `MOVE` command. Make sure you quote filenames to be sure: `"%%G"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd remove the /R from the for command. Also, don't put .csv after %%g anywhere. They will already have .csv appended as they are .csv files.

You're going to overwrite the solar.csv file, every time you move a CSV file BTW. If you wish the CSV files to be appended to solar.csv, then you may have to type them out to that file. E.g.

Before you loop...

```
if exist solar.csv del solar.csv
```

And in your loop...

```
type %%g >> solar.csv
```

Unless your service is going to process each solar.csv file and then you just overwrite the file with the next one, in which case you're golden :)

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I made the changes suggested, but I actually do want it to overwrite every time I move.  If I remove the /R will it still recursively walk that parent directory?  I want the ability to drop data in folders within the Data folder and have this run on everything in each folder.

Comment: I initially couldn't get it to work with /R, but if you need to do that and it works fine for you, then keep it, yes :)